# How can I draw a symbol like below for transformer by using circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

Hello all
I hope you are doing well. I am using circuitikz to draw the electrical circuit. now I need to draw a transformer symbol like below, but I don't know how to use it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \draw (0,0) to [voosource,fill=cyan!40, l=$T_1$,name=T1] (0,-2)  node[ground]{};
  \node [xshift=-13mm] at (T1.90) {$10/0.4$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but i get an error: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/voosource' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \draw (0,0) to [voosource] (0,-2)

Comment: What is your `circuitikz` version? I am on 0.9.0.

Comment: i am using latex2014

Comment: how can i update this package?

Comment: I am using MiKTeX, on Win10.  If your system is same, `MiKTeX Console` does it for you.

Comment: i am using texstudio

Comment: TextStudio is your writing environment. What is your operating system (Win or Mac or Unix/Linux?) and what is your TeX distribution? Based on your operating system and TeX distribution, please "google" it for updates.

Comment: If your distribution is not following updates in TeXlive (Ubuntu, for example) you can always use a  "circuitikzgit" style file. See at https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/

Comment: @ferahfeza Nice, +1, but notice that the `.90` label is always referred to the horizontally laid component. It would be more natural to just say `\draw (0,0) to [voosource,fill=cyan!40, l=$T_1$,a=$10/0.4$] (0,-2)` (but yes, in your way you have more control on the label position).

Comment: @Rmano, You are right, but I gave my answer to show the fillable and node properties on the component.