# draw a power system network

Tags: tikz-styles, circuitikz

I want to draw the following figure, however, I can not put the name for the bold vertical line, and then I can not show the circles.
I have tried to find the symbol for the transformer also, but I could not.

Could you help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Here is the code which I have tried (it is very basic)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations, positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
line/.style = {line width=1pt, draw=black},
shin/.style = {line, line width=3pt},
net node/.style = {circle, draw=black,line width=1.2pt,minimum width=0.8cm, inner sep=0pt, outer 
sep=0pt},
}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \path [shin] (0.8,-2) -- (0.8,2);
\path [shin] (4.8,-2) -- (4.8,2);
\path [shin] (8,-4) -- (8,4);
\path [line] (8,3) --  (9, 3);
\path [line] (8,2) --  (9, 2);
\path [line] (8,1) --  (9, 1);
\path [line] (8,0) --  (9, 0);
\path [line] (8,-1) --  (9, -1);
\path [line] (8,-2) --  (9, -2);
\path [line] (8,-3) --  (9, -3);
\path [line] (8,-3.5) --  (7, -3.5);
\coordinate(net node) at (9,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this post, you can find the transformer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493647/how-can-i-draw-a-symbol-like-below-for-transformer-by-using-circuitikz

Comment: Thank you for the link.

Comment: Also this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595368/38080 can give you an idea (the labels on the thick line are there). For the motor symbols, you can use an empty generator shape and superpose the text, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the following builds up on my previous answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595368/38080 --- I added a parameter to the `\bushere` macro, and then I show how to use `circuitikz` elements to mimic your diagram. You have still to complete it, but I think now it should be straightforward:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\bushere}[3]{% length, text above, text below
    % optional arguments do not work in paths
    %
    % starting point; draw an edge and then two nodes
    % save the position
    coordinate(tmp)
    % go up and do an edge down
    ++(0,#1) node[anchor=base]{#2} edge[ultra thick] ++(0,{-2*#1})
    % edges do not move the current point, go down to position the node
    ++(0,{-2*#1}) node[below]{#3}
    % go back to where we started
    (tmp)
}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{sources/fill=gray!20, resistors/fill=gray!20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[semithick]% default line width
    \draw (0,0)
        \bushere{1}{System Bus}{}
        to[oosourcetrans, name=trafo] ++(3,0)
        \bushere{1}{Low-side Bus}{} coordinate(low side)
        -- ++(1,0) coordinate(c1)
        to[generic, l={\small Feeder equivalent}, resistors/width=3] ++(5,0)
        coordinate(c2) -- ++(1,0)
        \bushere{3}{Load bus}{} coordinate(load)
        ;
    % capacitors
    \draw (c1) to[C] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};
    \draw (c2) to[C] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};
    \draw (low side) ++(0,-0.7) -- ++(-0.7,0) to[C] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};
    % variable arrow
    \draw[-Stealth] (trafo.center) ++(-0.5,-0.5) -- ++(1,1);
    % one load
    % position: start form the coord load, go up
    \ctikzset{bipoles/border margin=1.0}% see manual section 3.1.2
    \draw (load) ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0) node[rmetershape, fill=cyan, t=M]{}
        ++(1,0) node[right]{Motor 1};
    \draw (load) ++(0,-2) -- ++(0.5,0) node[draw, fill=orange!30, anchor=west]{Static Load};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Rmano. It is great

Comment: For the rectangular shape which connected to the Load bus, I have searched but I did not find anything like "rmetershape". Do you know what is the name of the symbol of that?

Comment: ...you can use a standard Tikz node, they are rectangular. `node[draw, fill=red]{whatever text here}`. I really advise reading the first tutorial in the TikZ manual....

Comment: Thank you su much.