# How to improve circuitikz single line diagrams?

Tags: circuitikz

I have come quite far with `circuitikz` in drawing good looking single-line diagrams.  There are however a few possible improvements.

Here are my result so far ( and the code is added below.)  The example might be a bit cluttered but it is easier to remove unwanted elements later:

[image: Single-line diagram]

The following can be improved:

1. `delta`, `wye` and `zig` symbols are too small and inconsistent thickness, compare with `vco`
2. there is no [three-phase autotransformer symbol](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Three-phase-star-connected-autotransformer-Symbol.png) (rhs symbol rotated +j and without the three-line symbols)
3. the `busbars` of length 0.3 with the label can be included as a symbol
4. the `osourcetrans` symbols should be scaled up 1/0.55 to be consistent with the other symbols (I still need to implement this in the source)
5. the `osourcetrans` labels are not correctly positioned and can be improved to include multiple lines as indicated
6. the grounding symbols:  `psolid`, `pres`, `pimp`, `parc`, `ssolid`, `sres`, `simp` or `sarc` can be added

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{comment}


%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{pgf,siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}
,separate-uncertainty}
\SendSettingsToPgf
%
\usepackage{relsize}



%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{lscape}



\usepackage[iso,english]{isodate}
%\renewcommand*\date[1]{{\isodate{#1}}}

\usepackage{steinmetz}% for \phasor{t}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}


\pgfplotsset{width=11cm, height=6cm, compat = 1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}
\makeatother
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
{\hfill\small\begin{circuitikz}[style={european resistor, resistors/scale=0.55, inductors/scale=0.55, blocks/scale=0.5, grounds/scale=0.55}]
 \draw (0,0) 
 to [vco,-,v>=\SI{24}{kV},l=$G$] ++(1,0) 
 to[oosourcetrans,name=t1,prim=delta,sec=wye,-,] ++(1.5,0)
 -- ++(0,0.6)
 to [L,-,l=$Z_1$] ++(1,0)
 to [L,-,l=$Z_2$] ++(1,0)
 -- ++(0,-0.6)
 to[oosourcetrans,name=t2,prim=wye,sec=zig,-,] ++(1.5,0) 
 to [L,-,l=$Z_c$] ++(1,0)
 to[oosourcetrans,name=t3,prim=delta,sec=wye,-,] ++(1.5,0) 
 to [R,-,l=$R_\text{load}$,] ++(1,0)
 ;
 % fixing the labels of oosourcetrans to correct the distance from the symbol
 \draw (t1.90) ++(0,0.15) node {\shortstack{$T_1$\\$_{24:132}$}};
 \draw (t2.90) ++(0,0.15) node {\shortstack{$T_2$\\$_{132:12}$}};
 \draw (t3.90) ++(0,0.15) node {\shortstack{$T_3$\\$_{12:\num{0.4}}$}};
 % add the correct earthing symbols to the oosourcetrans
 \draw (t1.-70)  ++(0,0.2) node[ground]{};
 \draw (t2.-70)  ++(0,0.2) to [R,-,resistors/scale=0.3,l={\scriptsize \SI{1.5}{\kilo\ampere}}] ++(0,-0.6) node[tlground]{};
 \draw (t2.-110)  ++(0,0.2) node[ground]{};
 \draw (t3.-70)  ++(0,0.2) node[ground]{};
% draw and label busbars (busbars are vertical with length = 0.6)
 \draw [ultra thick] (2.5,-0.9) -- ++(0,1.8)node [anchor=south] {$gs_1$}; % generation station busbar
 \draw [ultra thick] (3.5,0.3) -- ++(0,0.6)node [anchor=south] {$ts_1$}; % transmission station busbar
 \draw [ultra thick] (4.5,-0.9) -- ++(0,1.8)node [anchor=south] {$ds_1$}; % transmission station busbar
 \draw [ultra thick] (6,-0.3) -- ++(0,0.6) node [anchor=south] {$ds_2$}; % distribution station busbar
 \draw [ultra thick] (7,-0.3) -- ++(0,0.6) node [anchor=south] {$ms_1$}; % minisub
 \draw (2.5,-0.6) to [L,-,l=$Z_3$, v=$\Delta U_t$] ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}\hfill~}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, for the generator thickness you probably will like more `node[vsourcesinshape, rotate=90]`. I do not understand the ground references, and the symbols in the delta-etc transformer will grow up when you scale the symbol.

Comment: @Rmano The vsource does not include the lhs connection.  The line thickness of the internal symbol should be consistent.  I prefer the semithick line style. The relative size of the `ootransformer` will remain too small, even if the symbol are scaled up.  When doing fault analysis the grounding of the different components are indicated on the sld.  The star points are either:  not grounded, solidly grounded, grounded with resistor or impedance, or grounded with arc gap.

Comment: I still am unsure of what do you suggest here. I think you'll like the delta-star symbols thinner, like the sinusoidal in `vco`,  but the rest I really don't know. Probably my bad, I know nothing of power circuits (if you look at the manual, the `ootrasf` family was added by @olfline https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/397...). I will have a look to see if this is easy to solve, but please, try to do a question per question (you have 6 here), and for the new shapes, try to add a sketch or whatever to show what you mean... thanks!

Comment: @Rmano You are correct, both the size and the thickness of the `ootrasf` symbols.  I think the best addition will be the vertical black line busbar symbol.  I will add this as a separate item as soon as I have time.

Comment: They are just lines, you can use a macro like the one here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597815/38080 (wait, I am debugging a strange thing happening there...)

Comment: @Rmano Vertical bars on wires with labels.

Comment: Yes, `\bushere{size}{label above}{label below}` --- I am not sure I follow the problem

Comment: BTW --- you do not need the `,-,` options in every `to`, and moreover, the form you pass `style` is wrong. I will add an example as soon as possible, ok? Sorry if I am a bit terse on this.

Comment: @Rmano for busbars I would prefer a component,  \draw (0,0) 
 to [bus,l=$gs_1$] ++(1,0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to answer some of this. Let's start with the list of questions (please, next time, one question per post).

1. Yes, that is true --- I will contact the author to see if we can add a switch/parameter for this (Update: [it will be in the next release](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/544)). For now, I propose a brute-force patch of the symbols.
2. You can make a new symbol request on https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues, with references to printed things, and maybe somebody will do it (or you could try a go at it! You'll be welcome!)
3. I propose using a macro, like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597815/38080, but I provide a `bus` element here if you prefer the `to` syntax.
4. You were using a non-standard way of setting relative size, try again!
5. I provide two example for positioning a multi-line label, either using the provide `l2` facility, or with `\shortstack` and adjusting the distance;
6. I do not know how all those "ground styles" are. Please see point 2.

Now, the code does the following (I have put comments in it; notice that *this* is a *minimal* example, so I can work on it and not having tons of repetitions and distracting things...)

1. It starts patching the commands `\pgf@circ@delta`, etc., that are used to draw the transformers' symbols. You can find them in `pgfcircbipoles.tex` in your distribution. The first three resets the linewidth to the standard one for the circuit, the second three change the size a bit.
2. I define a bus as a very squeezed `fullgeneric`, with a parameter for the height, and a default of `3` (you can change this; the number are all proportional to the standard length)
3. If you do not want poles, no need to use `-` in every `to` command, it's the default.
4. There are two ways to position the label; using `l2` is more spacy (and in my opinion readable), using `\stackengine` is more compact --- a matter of tastes, I suppose.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% This should probably be added as a couple of parameters; I'll contact the author
% (see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/397). But for now, let's just patch
% patching linewidth
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@delta}
    {\pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    {\pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    {}{\FAIL}
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@zig}
    {\pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    {\pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    {}{\FAIL}
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@wye}
    {\pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    {\pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    {}{\FAIL}
% patching scale
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@delta}{-.01}{-.02}{}{\FAIL}
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@wye}{-.015}{-.02}{}{\FAIL}
\patchcmd{\pgf@circ@zig}{-.015}{-.02}{}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

% define the bus (ab-)using the fullgeneric component
%
\tikzset{bus/.style={fullgeneric, %
        bipoles/fullgeneric/width=0.02, bipoles/fullgeneric/height=#1
    },
    bus/.default=3
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european] % do not use style={}!
    % this is the correct way to set the class values
    \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.55, inductors/scale=0.55,
         blocks/scale=0.5, grounds/scale=0.55}
    \draw (0,0)
    % choose one of the following two
    % to[oosourcetrans, name=t1, prim=delta, sec=wye,  
    %     l=\shortstack{$T_1$\\${}_{24:132}$}, label distance=-6pt] ++(3,0)
    to[oosourcetrans, name=t1, prim=delta, sec=wye,
        l2=$T_1$ and {\scriptsize 24:132}, l2 halign=c] ++(3,0)
    to[bus, l=$gs_1$, name=gs1] ++(1,0)
    (gs1.center) ++(0, 0.6) to [L,l=$Z_1$] ++(2,0)
    to [bus=1, l=$ts_1$] ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS You can notice why I prefer the macro for the bus: using the macro, as in the linked post, the bus has a zero width, so that the components between buses are naturally centered. If you use a `to[bus...` syntax, the component has the size of the path, and you have to take into account the distances by yourself, and you have to manage the leading wires. If you use the definition in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597815/38080, the circuit will be:

```latex
\begin{circuitikz}[european] % do not use style={}!
    % this is the correct way to set the class values
    \ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.55, inductors/scale=0.55,
        blocks/scale=0.5, grounds/scale=0.55}
    \draw (0,0)
    % choose one of the following two
    % to[oosourcetrans, name=t1, prim=delta, sec=wye,
    %     l=\shortstack{$T_1$\\${}_{24:132}$}, label distance=-6pt] ++(3,0)
    to[oosourcetrans, name=t1, prim=delta, sec=wye,
        l2=$T_1$ and {\scriptsize 24:132}, l2 halign=c] ++(3,0)
    \bushere{1.5}{$gs_1$}{}
    ++(0, 0.6) to [L,l=$Z_1$] ++(2,0)
    \bushere{0.5}{$ts_1$}{};
\end{circuitikz}
```

with this result:

[image]

PPS yes, the buses are a bit asymmetric. This is due to a bug in `\bushere` that makes space for the upper label... the solution (any one of them) is left to the student!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the rhs wire of any component?

Comment: you can use the component as a node, using the node shape name, and then add wires by hand. But not in a `to` command; the `to` command literally means "draw a line from here to here placing X in the middle".

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer.  Who am I trying to fool?  +1 for the `stackengine` plug!

Comment: @skvery for the next release: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/544

Comment: @Rmano Refer 4.5.8.1.  Have a look, the wire ends are not clipped in the figure displayed.  It might be from the red circle?

Comment: @skvery the red circle has black wires. So you are seeing the wire going to the red `esource`. If you want the red `esource` to have red wires, you have to put `[color=red]` in the `\draw` options. It's explained in the "color" section of the manual.

Comment: See (drawing the red `esource` with red wires before the transf: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6414907/119697731-cd8a8300-be50-11eb-81aa-fd1e502cd0eb.png