# How to create complex three-phase circuit with Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

this is my first question here, so I am going to be brief. I want to make this three- phase circuit, but I don't know how to start with Circuitikz. This is the figure:[image]

Comment: Hi José, welcome! You have posted an exactly equal question that has been closed because it seems a "please do it for me" one. I suggest that you open the documentation of `Ti*k*Z` and `circuitikz` and try something by yourself, and when (or if!) you get stuck but have something done, you can ask a specific question here.  You can start here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597643/draw-a-power-system-network or with the first and third example in `circuitikz`, that are probably usable for that.

Comment: Notice that you do not need to repost a closed question --- you can edit the question to make it better, and then it will be reopened (if it got better, clearly)