# Trying to implement some power electronics symbols with tikz

Tags: circuits

So i want do draw using tikzset something like the figure below

[image]

For now i'm struggling to create symbol (1), the transformer... I have this:

```
\tikzset{transformer symbol/.style={
  circle,
  draw,
  scale=1.5,
 }
}
```

How can i add another circle and text above? I want to be able to change the scale of things in case the circuit gets to big or to small

Comment: Did you take a look at the `circuitikz` pacakge? I think it already has everything you need.

Comment: Maybe you can start from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597643/draw-a-power-system-network ?